# Firefox Save HTML Source Locally

Tags: html, firefox, web, frontend

Is there any way to edit HTML code that is local on my drive in Firefox's Inspector and save the changes?  Or any way to quickly edit and save HTML and view it in the browser rather than switching back and forth to a text editor?

I know you can do this in Chrome by adding the file to your workspace, but I'm wondering if Firefox has something similar.

I see that a similar question was asked about Firebug back in 2010.  However, I was wondering if anything had changed since then, due to Firebug being deprecated and the functionality being available in Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving the manipulated DOM/HTML after editing it with Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184862/saving-the-manipulated-dom-html-after-editing-it-with-firebug)

Comment: That question was from 2010 and Firebug is deprecated now, so I was wondering if there was any way currently.

Comment: The answer there still applies to the newer Firefox Web developer tools using the "Inspector".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no modern/active extension to do this as far as I know. Even with FireBug it's still not very intuitive.

Your best bet is to use an editor that has a live edit, like Brackets or PhpStorm.